# Remove invalid character from multipart request header and body

Tags: spring-mvc, multipart

I need to provide an API that consumes a multipart request. Unfortunately, the client (out of my control) sends an invalid character ('=') as part of the boundary subpart of the Content-type header. I was thinking about writing a servlet filter to correct the Content-Type header as well as the boundaries within the request. The header part is already done but im struggling with replacing the boundary within the request body which contains multiple parts consisting of application/json as well as application/octet-stream (hence if possible I would like to fix the boundaries on the fly without necessarily reading the entire body). I'd greatly appreciate some pointers here to get me going into the right direction.

Here is the filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
public class FixBoundaryFilter implements Filter {

    //Actual header value example: "multipart/form-data; boundary=WhooHooZeerOoonie="
    Pattern headerValuePattern = Pattern.compile("multipart/form-data; boundary=([a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\-=]+)");

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
        LOGGER.info("########## Initiating custom {} ##########", FixBoundaryFilter.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        FixBoundaryRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new FixBoundaryRequestWrapper(request);
        String contentTypeHeaderValue = wrappedRequest.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(contentTypeHeaderValue)) {
            Matcher matcher = headerValuePattern.matcher(contentTypeHeaderValue);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                String updatedHeader = String.format("multipart/form-data; boundary=\"%s\"", matcher.group(1));
                wrappedRequest.removeHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
                wrappedRequest.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, updatedHeader);
            }
        }

        //call next filter in the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

Here is the wrapper:

```
public class FixBoundaryRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public FixBoundaryRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private final Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headerMap.put(name, value);
    }

    public void removeHeader(String name) {
        headerMap.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(name);
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            headerValue = headerMap.get(name);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        names.addAll(headerMap.keySet());
        return Collections.enumeration(names);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            values.add(headerMap.get(name));
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(values);
    }
}
```